# Derivative of a integration

Tags: calculus

Calc $F'(x), F(x) = \int^{x}_{0}f(t)dt, f(t) = t$ for $t \neq 1, f(t) = 2$ for $t = 1$

The answer is supposed to be "f(x)"
But what i think is $f(x)$ for $x \neq 1$, why i am wrong?

Is not
$$F(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$$

?

So
$F'(1) = 1, f(1) = 2, F'(1) \neq f(1)$

Comment: You are right. The fundamental theorem of calculus require $f$ to be continuous. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part

Comment: Also $f$ is not the derivative of anything since a derivative has to have the Darboux property.

Comment: When you say "supposed to be $f(x)$," do you mean an answer key says it is (in which case your instructor is wrong) or that you expected it to be $f(x)$?

Comment: The answer say it